# Login with Google for UWP and Xamarin.Forms (android) versions of an app

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have created 2 apps, one in Xamarin Forms (for the Google Play Store) and one  in UWP (Desktop & Mobile). I want to implement a way in which a user can login with a 3rd Party (preferably Google) so that he can access his data from both apps. I need a way to identify the user.

I have already implemented login with Google using Firebase for the Xamarin Forms app, that generates me a UserId. Since Firebase is not yet officially supported by UWP, I tried using OAuth2 in order to login with Google but in the UserInfo provided I can not see a way to identify the user that I can use in both apps.

Below is the structure of UserInfo I get from OAuth2

```
{
  "sub": "somenumber",
  "name": "somename",
  "given_name": "someGivenName",
  "family_name": "someFamilyName",
  "profile": "https://plus.google.com/somenumber",
  "picture": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-someURL.jpg",
  "gender": "someGender",
  "locale": "someCountry"
}
```

Using the "sub" property would probably not be good since the user can change it and Google will renounce G+. Same is true with other account values like the username.

What approach can I use in order to successfully identify the user in both apps?

**EDIT:**
Login with Google using Firebase gives me the email address of the user (that is unique and will not be changed). So my challenge seems to be finding a way of getting the email address of a user after logging in with google account in UWP. All the examples I found are refering to the soon-to-be obsolete g+ api.

Comment: where you able to connect you xamarin.forms app to firebase auth and google? i am only able to do it with mail and password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have found a good solution for my issue that can also help others in the same situation:

So, if you want to use third party login and you do not have the same support on all platforms (i.e. Firebase login and UWP), the only info regarding the user that is unique, will not be changed in the future and does not depend on the server you're working with, is the email address. That can be used to identify the user.

Let's pick Google as a Third Party Sign In:

For Xamarin Forms the third party login documentation is very scarce compared to Xamarin.Android, but I have found a very good tutorial [here](http://albertomontesdeoca.xyz/firebase-para-aplicaciones-xamarin-forms-parte-1-firebaseauth-para-android/). Yes, it is written in spanish, but google chrome will translate it just right. To get the email instead of a generated Id just replace

```
MessagingCenter.Send(FirebaseAuthService.KEY_AUTH, FirebaseAuthService.KEY_AUTH, sg.IdToken);
```

with

```
MessagingCenter.Send(FirebaseAuthService.KEY_AUTH, FirebaseAuthService.KEY_AUTH, sg.Email);
```

Make sure you read all instructions in the "Use your own credentials" paragraph - you must change the bundle id in the protocol scheme of the manifest.

Now, for getting the google email address with UWP:

Again, very scarce documentation. You need to download the Oauth2 samples for .Net from [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows). Then, in the OAuthUniversalApp, when making the first request, specify scope=email, like this:

```
 string authorizationRequest = string.Format("{0}?response_type=code&scope=email%20profile&redirect_uri={1}&client_id={2}&state={3}&code_challenge={4}&code_challenge_method={5}",
                authorizationEndpoint,
                System.Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectURI), 
                clientID,
                state,
                code_challenge,
                code_challenge_method);
```

Now you have the google e-mail in both platforms, so the user can use his Android device or Windows PC to login with google. Another important thing is to make transparent to the user that you will have access to the email, and use an encryption algorithm if you choose store it, to avoid security issues.